# How to append a incremental number for each insert of record in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a column ProductName in Products table. User is able to duplicate the product. While duplicating the product I have to copy all fields from the Products table for the particular product and create new record except for ProductName field. The ProductName field should be as follows:

for 1st duplicate: ProductName_Copy_1
for 2nd duplicate: ProductName_Copy_2
etc

Can anyone suggest me how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery to generate the number:

```
insert into product
select
  concat(productname, '_',
    (select count(*) from product
     where productname like concat(p.productname, '%')),
  col2, col3, ....
from product p
where id = <original product id to copy>
```

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314202/why-was-this-question-considered-primarily-opinion-based

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are using phpmyadmin, there is an auto_increment attribute you can set to rows. Each row will be uniquely identified by that value.

More information can be found here 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html